# Default folder deleted - can not change back keybinding theme

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool, shortcut-keys

I accidently removed Default folder from /usr/share/themes and now can not change the Keybindig theme back to default under advanced setting -> theme. Default option is simply gone, not there anymore. Couldn't get it back... 
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome shell.
Any thoughts on what can bring this option back?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/themes/Default
```

The command shows you which packages use (and create) this directory. In my case the output is: `libgtk1.2-common, libgtk2.0-common: /usr/share/themes/Default`.
So the best idea would be to reinstall both packages:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgtk1.2-common libgtk2.0-common
```

So they create the directory and fill it with the correct content.

Answer (score 0):

I better not ask how and why did you delete it, but anyways, probably you could:

1: reinstall system (aka: upgrade to the same version)

2: get the /usr/share folder from another installation, or from the liveCD/DVD

3: create the folder, and add a new theme

Hope that helps, good luck!
Cheers!